# Is there a shortcut to check for multiple columns in a table that have the same value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to check for `10-12 columns` in a table:

```
amount1=0
amount2=0
.
.
.
.
amount10=0
```

Is there a shortcut by which I'd be able to cluster these fields together, given that I am checking for the same value for all of them.

This is lengthening the query. Can this be optimized in some way?

Comment: The best option you have is to normalize the table.

Comment: Please pick one database engine.

Comment: Are you checking for the same value, or zero?

Comment: @Strawberry oops, you're right. That's about MySQL and Oracle Database. It seems I mixed them up this time. Removed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an `IN` statement:

```
Select *
From table
Where 0 in (amount0, amount1, amount2, amount10);
```

That might shorten it a little, but it may not be the most performant solution.

Comment: 'may not be' - that is certainly an understatement!!

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't recommend this, but it's what the OP was asking for. Their original approach would have been better than this. Best option is redesigning the database and properly normalizing the design, but again, that wasn't the OP's question.

Comment: If an OP asks where they can find a good cliff to jump off, the answer might not be directions to the coast.

Comment: Well, others recommended normalizing. Since I doubt that this ```IN``` statement will result in the OP's death, I answered the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I created a table, inserted 1.25m rows of data for columns `amount0` - `amount15` and then ran queries using `IN` and using direct comparison of each column and the results were almost identical Explain plan is the same for both and the execution time is between 0.004-0.010ms for each over 30 executions with the average being 0.006ms. I created a normalized table with one column, inserted the 1.25m randomized rows and the results are virtually identical. The normalized table returned between 0.003-0.010ms after 30 executions with the average being 0.005ms.